# IBAction to send text to a NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Sending string value to a text field after button is pressed.
This is for a macOSX application using swift. (Cocoa)

```
@IBAction func power(_ sender: Any) {
    let stringvalue =
}
```

Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: what string do you want and what is the name of your text field outlet?

Comment: @Martheli (OP Edited but forgot to mention you)